# How to login and web scrape "support.oracle.com" using python3 requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, request, wget

Am trying to webscrape below mentioned URL using python requests, but unable to make it.

Url: https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=1439822.1

Not Working Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update(headers)


r = s.get("https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=1439822.1", auth=('user@email.com', 'mypass'), allow_redirects=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

**Expected Output:** (Got output via web-browser, post successful login. Actually need below output on command line)

[image]

**Current Output:** (Shows again the login page)
[image]

**Note**: Am able to achieve through wget command, but i need to do with python request.

```
wget --user "user@email.com" --password "mypass" "https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=1439822.1" -O /root/webout.html
```

Appreciate your help !!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What is your specific question?

Comment: Can you show us the requests code you are using?

Comment: Code:

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

    s = requests.session()
    s.headers.update(headers)

    r = s.get("https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=1439822.1", auth=('user@email.com', 'mypass'), allow_redirects=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())

Comment: Code is very hard to read in a comment.  Please edit the question to add the code.  Also explain what results you are getting from the code.

Comment: "Not Working" doesn't tell us much.  What does it do?  Do you get an error?

Comment: All i need post login source code of website "https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=1439822.1", so that i can able to do web scrap for my requirement.

Comment: You first log in and then scrape. To find the request to login, login normally and catch the request made.

Comment: @Nathan: Could you please elaborate? Appreciate your effort !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally Found the Answer !!**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=1439822.1", auth=('user@email.com', 'mypass'), allow_redirects=True)

full_fetch = requests.get(r.url, auth=('user@email.com', 'mypass), allow_redirects=True) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(full_fetch.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```